# Is there any way to adjust the keyboard height in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change the decimal pad keyboard height in iOS. I am getting height difference b/w default keyboard height and decimal pad keyboard.

```
func resizeKeyboard(note: NSNotification){
    let userInfo = note.userInfo!
    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt

    var frameEnd = self.view .convert(((userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue), from: nil)

    if note.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow{
         Keyboard appears
         desiredHeight = 260
    }else if note.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide{
         Keyboard hides
         desiredHeight = 260
    }

    self.heightConstraint.constant = desiredHeight
    self.view .setNeedsLayout()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
        self.view .setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: why do you need to change the keyboard height ? as we cannot change system keyboards.. Then what is the need of it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the height of the system keyboards, and as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) says, that is not always the same:

> You should always use the information in these notifications as
>   opposed to assuming the keyboard is a particular size or in a
>   particular location. The size of the keyboard is not guaranteed to be
>   the same from one input method to another and may also change between
>   different releases of iOS.

This means that your code needs to look at `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to figure out what the actual keyboard height is, and adjust/scroll the rest of your UI to fit that.